# Meaning of "challenged"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, past-participles

I'm translating [a lawsuit (PDF)](http://law.wlu.edu/deptimages/powell%20archives/76-15_ContinentalTVGTESylvania4.pdf). There are three sentences that use "challenged" and I wonder what it means in each case:

1. > As to interbrand competition, Sylvania, unlike Schwinn, had an insignificant market share at the time it adopted its **challenged distribution practice** and enjoyed no consumer preference that would allow its retailers to charge a premium over other brands.

   (Page 1, line 13.)
2. > This was precisely the theory on which the Government successfully **challenged** Schwinn's customer restrictions in this Court.

   (Page 3, line 3.)
3. > This Court relied on Schwinn's market position as one reason not to apply the rule of reason to the vertical restraints **challenged** there.

   (Page 6, line 7.)

Please reword in plain English because I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

In this context it means **disputed** *(in a legal sense).*